# Order 2 columns by the combinations of both of the max values in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, sql-order-by

For example, I have this table (the values are completely random):

```
long | lat | fare_amout | total_people |
----------------------------------------
23,32 64,67    450           4
64,67 78,27    543           2
25,32 98,07    458           1
12,32 44,65    323           7
93,42 24,19    398           9
...
```

So basically the total_people is the number of times that the same coordinates appear on the table (I got the result by doing a simple count), the fare_amout is the average of the values that have the same coordinates.
I want to order my table in order to have the coordinates who have a higher combination of fare_amount and total_people on the first line. Any suggestions?

Comment: Please explain what you mean by "higher combination of fare_amount and total_people".

Comment: You should show us the wanted result, not just describe it.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want?

```
order by total_people desc, fare_amount desc
```

It orders by `total_people` first.  When there are ties, then by `fare_amount`.

If by "higher combination" you mean the total amount paid, then you can instead use:

```
order by total_people * fare_amount desc
```